# Meaning of adj-なるときゃなる

Tags: grammar

> 「盲腸なんて、年にかかわらず、痛くなるときゃ**なる**んだ。」
>   For things like appendicitis, regardless of age, when it gets painful ???

I don't understand what the second なる is referring to in this sentence. 
Is it just an abbreviation of 痛くなるときは痛くなる, reinforcing that pain is not related to age? I can't think what else it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're perfectly correct, it's 痛くなるときは痛くなる. The expression implies you cannot predict or control when it hurts, similarly to the English saying "what will happen will happen".